# When do I need to initialize a String?

Tags: java, string, initialization, switch-statement

Going through some `switch` command tutorials from various sources. I am trying to create a small program based on this SwitchDemo tutorial ( I have removed some repeated code to save space):

```
public class SwitchDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int month = 8;
    String monthString;
    switch (month) {
        case 1:  monthString = "January";
                 break;
        case 2:  monthString = "February";
                 break;
        case 3:  monthString = "March";
                 break;
        default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                 break;
    }
    System.out.println(monthString);
}
}
```

In this code `monthString` does not need to be initialized in the line `String monthString;`. However I want to add user input to the code using `Scanner` as follows:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class App2 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int month = scan.nextInt();

    String monthString;

    switch (month) {
    case 1:
        monthString = "January";
        break;      
    case 2:
        monthString = "February";
        break;
    case 3: 
        monthString = "March";
        break;
    default: 
        System.out.println("Invalid month");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(monthString);
}
```

}

In this case the code does not work and Eclipse tells me I need to initialize `monthString`; eclipse corrects it by adding `= null` to `String monthString`.

What is the reason for this?

P.s I am completely new to Java, so could you explain it like you would to someone who does not know any programming?

Thanks

Comment: In example one, default gives the string a value. In example 2, you don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `monthString` is a *local* variable and there's a path you can take where it's not initialized and you're still trying to use it.

That's just not allowed in Java.  I think the reason is it's an easy way for Java to prevent you from making a mistake.  It forces you to acknowledge that you haven't set `monthString` to anything yet but you're *still* trying to use it.  9 times out of 10, that's an mistake on the developers part, so Java won't let you do it.

One way to fix it is to set `monthString` to something in your `default:`.  You can also initialize it to null, as @Eran said.

Answer (score 1):

You can either initialize it to null when declaring it :

`String monthString = null;`

or give it some default value in the `default` clause of the switch.

```
default: 
    System.out.println("Invalid month");
    monthString = null; // or some other default value
    break;
}
```

If you don't do one of the two, you might reach `System.out.println(monthString);` before the String is ever initialized, which is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, any time you can get to a statement, any variable used in that statement has to have been initialized.

In your second example, the `default` case breaks out of the `switch` statement, but the code then executes the next statement after the switch: `System.out.println(monthString)`. So, the variable has to have been initialized in all code paths that lead there, but it wasn't in the `default` case.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense and I understand more about paths as a result. I changed the system.out.println(); line in default to monthString = "default text" as I have for the cases and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that it's part of the Java language specification. You are not allowed to access the value of a local variable (or blank final field) if the variable has not been "definitely assigned". The compiler performs an analysis to ensure assignment occurs before an access, no matter what code path is taken to the access.

In the case of your second example, the path through the default switch case never assigns a value to `monthString`, and then the value of the variable is accessed in the println statement.

The full definite assignment rules are pretty complex. You can read them in chapter 16 of the spec [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could try something like this:

```
String monthString;
switch (month) {
case 1:
    monthString = "January";
    break;      
case 2:
    monthString = "February";
    break;
case 3: 
    monthString = "March";
    break;
default: 
    monthString = "Invalid month";
    break;
}
System.out.println(monthString);
```

In order to use a local variable in java it must be initialized to something even if that something is setting it equal to `null`.
What eclipse is doing is following all of the different paths between creating `monthString` and where it is used in `System.out.println(monthString)` and determining that there is no place where the `monthString` is initialized.

If you were to declare `monthString` within the enclosing `SwitchDemo` class then your code would also be valid because there is no way for eclipse to determine if another method has set `monthString`. (You would of course have to declare `monthString` as static if you were to do this because you can only access static variables from within a static method).